# Returning BigQuery data filtered on nested objects

Tags: arrays, nested, google-bigquery

I'm trying to create a query which returns data which is filtered on 2 nested objects.  I've added (1) and (2) to the code to indicate that I want results from two different nested objects (I know that this isn't a valid query).  I've been looking at WITHIN RECORD but I can't get my head around it.

```
SELECT externalIds.value(1) AS appName, externalIds.value(2) AS driverRef, SUM(quantity)/ 60 FROM [billing.tempBilling]
WHERE callTo = 'example' AND externalIds.type(1) = 'driverRef' AND externalIds.type(2) = 'applicationName'
GROUP BY appName, driverRef ORDER BY appName, driverRef;
```

The data loaded into BigQuery looks like this:

```
{
  "callTo": "example",
  "quantity": 120,
  "externalIds": [
    {"type": "applicationName", "value": "Example App"},
    {"type": "driverRef", "value": 234}
  ]
}
```

The result I'm after is this:

```
+-------------+-----------+----------+
|   appName   | driverRef | quantity |
+-------------+-----------+----------+
| Example App |    123    |   12.3   |
| Example App |    234    |  132.7   |
| Test App    |    142    |   14.1   |
| Test App    |    234    |   17.4   |
| Test App    |    347    |  327.5   |
+-------------+-----------+----------+
```

Answer (score 1):

If all of the quantities that you need to sum are within the same record, then you can use WITHIN RECORD for this query.  Use NTH() WITHIN RECORD to get the first and second values for a field in the record.  Then use HAVING to perform the filtering because it requires a value computed by an aggregation function.

```
SELECT callTo,
       NTH(1, externalIds.type) WITHIN RECORD AS firstType,
       NTH(1, externalIds.value) WITHIN RECORD AS maybeAppName,
       NTH(2, externalIds.type) WITHIN RECORD AS secondType,
       NTH(2, externalIds.value) WITHIN RECORD AS maybeDriverRef,
       SUM(quantity) WITHIN RECORD
FROM [billing.tempBilling]
HAVING callTo LIKE 'example%' AND
       firstType = 'applicationName' AND
       secondType = 'driverRef';
```

If the quantities to be summed are spread across multiple records, then you can start with this approach and then group by your keys and sum those quantities in an outer query.